# Intent from notification does not have extras

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications

This seem to be a common problem and I went through all the related questions I could find already:
[Activity isn't picking up new intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5628382/activity-isnt-picking-up-new-intent), [Why extra data (integer) is not sent in android notification intent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456655/why-extra-data-integer-is-not-sent-in-android-notification-intent), [Notification passes old Intent Extras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370324/notification-passes-old-intent-extras/9330144), [Can't put extras for an intent in notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098893/cant-put-extras-for-an-intent-in-notification), [android pending intent notification problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009059/android-pending-intent-notification-problem); but still cannot figure this out.

Problem is the same. I set a notification with a PendingIntent carrying some extra information and I don't get it on the other side.

Here is the code for generating the notification:

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.icon, getResources().getString(R.string.notification_ticker), System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL | Notification.FLAG_ONLY_ALERT_ONCE;

Intent start_test = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
start_test.putExtra("start_test", true);
start_test.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), start_test, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, getResources().getString(R.string.notification_title), getResources().getString(R.string.notification_content, expired), pi);
nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

And on the other side:

```
boolean start_test=getIntent().getBooleanExtra("start_test", false);
```

The bundle is actually not there (getExtras() returns null).

I tried the different flags for `PendingIntent.getActivity` (`FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`, `FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT`, `FLAG_ONE_SHOT`), none of those helped.

As shown in the code, I use getCurrentMillis to make sure the requestID changes....

Also found that in MyActivity, `onCreate` and `onNewIntent` are not getting called. only `onResume` is. Even though the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` is set... ?

Am I missing something very simple ?

Comment: If you only want to put a single extra then forget using `Bundle`. Simply use `new_intent.putExtra("start_test", true)` then at the other end just use `getIntent.getBooleanExtra("start_test", false)`

Comment: Yes, I tried that way also, it did not change anything... still not getting it on the other side

Comment: Is your application running (or in the background) when this happens? Is `MyActivity` on top of the activity stack?

Comment: @DavidWasser, Yes, MyActivity is still running in the background (onDestroy has not been called). Not sure if it was on top of the activity stack or not in that task.

Comment: new_intent.putExtra("start_test", true) then at the other end just use getIntent.getBooleanExtra("start_test", false) is not working

Comment: Referencing to this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198558/how-to-send-parameters-from-a-notification-click-to-an-activity/47156455#47156455

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Setting `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` for the notification Intent will cause the following:

- If the activity is **not** already running in a task, a new task will be started and the Intent will be delivered to the activity in `onCreate()`
- However, if the activity is already running in a task, that task will be brought to the foreground. That's all. The Intent will **not** be delivered and `onNewIntent()` will not be called.

If you want the Intent to **actually be delivered** you need to specify:

```
start_test.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | 
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

It makes **no difference** whether the `launchMode` of the activity is `singleTop` or not, you still must specify `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` in the Intent.

**Note:** If the activity is already running in a task and the activity is **not** on top of the activity stack in that task, the task will be brought to the foreground. That's all. The Intent will **not** be delivered. The only way to make this happen would be to add `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` to the other 2 flags, but this may not be what you want to happen (depends on your specific scenario).

See my (still) open issue on Google code at http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17137

Comment: Thanks a lot of the detailed explanation. Also had to set the flag in PendingIntent.getActivity to FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT otherwise onNewIntent would be called several times. Not exactly sure why, but it seems to work as expected now.

Comment: Because it always takes the firs intent delivered to it, not the one from notification. So you will need to override - 
`@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}`

so your intents will be received.

Answer (score 56):

I just added the `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag to my pending intent, and it started working for me (skipped all flags for Intent).

Example Code:

```
PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! :) No need to add anything more.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it is easier to implement

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me on api 16 - however, this did on 16 - 23 perfectly

Comment: This is the right answer. an additional note that if the activity is already open  then onStart isn't fired again so the intent need to be checked in onResume

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped me save more time. No need to add anything more.

Comment: I needed this to get extras passed with a notification on API level 19.

Comment: After at least 2-3 hours of search, this saved me. Thank alot

Answer (score 7):

1. If not needed then **avoid** setting your activity in manifest  as  a single task. omit this line or change it to singleTop if you can:

   ```
     android:launchMode="singleTask”
   ```
2. If you must have a single task then in pending intent set flags to :
   Intent.**FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** | Intent.**FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK**
   And  PendingIntent.**FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT**.

   ```
   resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
   pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, resultIntent,    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT );
   ```
3. If you have a single task - Reset your extras in your activity inside onNewIntent() by **setIntent(intent);**

   ```
   protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
          setIntent(intent);
          ... 
    }
   ```

Comment: In my case it worked well with having `FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` to pending intent

Answer (score 3):

You can send extras in intent following way

```
PendingIntent contentIntent ;
Intent intent = new Intent(this,TestActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("extra","Test");
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);

stackBuilder.addParentStack(ArticleDetailedActivity.class);

contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

To Get Intent extra value in Test Activity class you need to write following code :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
 String extra = intent.getStringExtra("extra") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

When app is not running or is in background and user clicks on Notification in tray, you can get Intent extra and check the keys:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Log.d("RC","MainActivity.onCreate() called");

    if (getIntent().getExtras() != null){
        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();
        Log.d("RC", "MainActivity.onCreate() : keys count = " + extra.keySet().size());

        for ( String key : extra.keySet()) {
            Log.d("RC","MainActivity.onCreate() : key = " + key + " = " + extra.getString(key));
        }

    }
}
```

This will show:

```
D/RC: MainActivity.onCreate() called
D/RC: MainActivity.onCreate() : keys count = 8
D/RC: MainActivity.onCreate() : key = google.delivered_priority = high
D/RC: MainActivity.onCreate() : key = google.sent_time = null
D/RC: MainActivity.onCreate() : key = google.ttl = null
D/RC: MainActivity.onCreate() : key = google.original_priority = high
D/RC: MainActivity.onCreate() : key = from = 631131412302
D/RC: MainActivity.onCreate() : key = google.message_id = 0:1627370460932539%952b1da9952b1da9
D/RC: MainActivity.onCreate() : key = gcm.n.analytics_data = null
D/RC: MainActivity.onCreate() : key = collapse_key = com.reflectcode.demo.cloudmessaging
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler approach: the real problem is that the Intent, being to the same target, gets replaced. I've solved this by just created a new service, a "NotificationDismissalService". The only intent going to that service is the setDeleteIntent item. Because it's a unique service, the parameters do not get replaced. The body of NotificationDismissalService (and it would really be one such dismissal service per unique intent type) is a simple implementation of "onStartCommand" that sends an intent to the preferred service (reading/writing the correct parameters). Because that's an actual send of a service, without a pendingintent in between, it works just fine.

Answer (score -2):

I have used something like this

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, DoSomething.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context, 
        0, 
        myIntent, 
        Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Check out the full example [here](http://www.panayiotisgeorgiou.net/start-activity-once-notification-clicked/)

Comment: This is not working code at all.