# getIntent().getExtras() returns null Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I want to open a fragment when the app receive a notification for further processing. In my MainActivity.java, `getIntent().getExtras()` always return `null`.

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
  private void sendNotification(String title, String messageBody, String newsID, String newsType) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("newsID", String.valueOf(newsID));
    extras.putString("newsType", String.valueOf(newsType));
    intent.putExtras(extras);

    Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
Bundle i = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (i != null) {

        for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
            String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);

            Log.e("News ID", value);
            if (key.equals("newsID") ) {
                dbHelper.insertNewsID(String.valueOf(value));

                //show news details
                   getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(ng.naijaleague.R.id.frame_container, new NewsDetails())
                        .addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        }
        String newsType = getIntent().getExtras().getString("newsType");
        if ("newsType".equals(newsType) ) {
            String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("newsType");

            if("Local".equals(value)){
                //add news type to shared preference
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("newType", "Local");
                editor.apply();
            }else{
                //add news type to shared preference
                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putString("newType", "Foreign");
                editor.apply();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have followed through all the solutions I found on SO but none of them have worked so far. What must be wrong with the code?

Comment: did you see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11551195/intent-from-notification-does-not-have-extras

Comment: Simply put it, you're sending the intent to `SplashScreenActivity` (from `MyFirebaseMessagingService`) and you're recovering it in `MainActivity`.

Comment: @SrikarReddy Sorry, trying different method that's why. I am actually sending it to MainActivity

Comment: Try setting extras before creating a pending intent like Pratik mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to everyone, all the answers moved me closer to making it work but I needed to change the PendingIntent to the following to nail it.

```
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Thanks...<3

Answer (score 3):

POST THIS 4 lines before making **PendingIntent** Object :P

```
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("newsID", String.valueOf(newsID));
extras.putString("newsType", String.valueOf(newsType));
intent.putExtras(extras);
```

LIKE:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

//PUT HERE
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("newsID", String.valueOf(newsID));
extras.putString("newsType", String.valueOf(newsType));
intent.putExtras(extras);

//THEN Create PendingIntent Object
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

Hope it will helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

**move extras assign before Pending intent is created**

add flag:

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

Note than when using  **PendingIntent.getActivity(...)** the activity will be started outside of the context of an existing activity, so you must use the **Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK** launch flag in the Intent.